After the algorithm written in C++ is compiled into a dll, the calculation speed becomes slower
After the C++ algorithm uses the MKL function library and acceleration, 10 rounds take about 280ms, but after extracting it and turning it into a dll library, the 10 rounds reach 500ms.
I have read some questions about using dll make the program become slower.The answere told me that there is no different between the cpp code and dll. They will have the same speed.
So may I make the misstake by call dll in the program?
Here is my call code.
the cpp code:
auto starttime = system_clock::now();
cleanData = ssveP.getWarmFilter(newData);

std::vector<std::vector<double>> eps;
std::vector<std::vector<double>> pred;

vector<vector<vector<vector<double>>>> corr;
vector<vector<vector<double>>>filterData;

ssveP.testPhaseOnlineADA(res, pred, eps, corr, ssveP, filterData, cleanData, M, method, T, 0);

duration<double> diff = system_clock::now() - starttime;
std::cout << endl << "所耗时间为：" << diff.count() << "s";

the dll code:
 __declspec(dllexport) Result testPhaseOnlineADA(std::vector<std::vector<double>> newData)
    {
        //double* result = new double[2];
        Result result;
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> epsilons;
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> predLabels;
        vector<vector<vector<vector<double>>>> corrCoef;
        vector<vector<vector<double>>>filterData;
        int res = -1;
        string method = "DW11";
        double T = -0.005;
        int C = 0;
        vector<vector<vector<double>>>cleanData;
        cleanData = DWT.getWarmFilter(newData);
        DWT.testPhaseOnlineADA(res, predLabels, epsilons, corrCoef, DWT, filterData, cleanData, M, method, T, C);
        //std::cout << "epsilons[0][0]:" << epsilons[0][0] << std::endl;

        double epsMin;
        epsMin = epsilons[0][0];
        int wIdx = 0;
        for (int m = 0; m < epsilons.size(); m++)
        {
            if (epsMin > epsilons[m][0])
            {
                epsMin = epsilons[m][0];
                wIdx = m;
            }
        }
        if (epsMin < T)
        {
            res = predLabels[wIdx][0] + 1;
        }

       /* result[0] = res;
        result[1] = wIdx;*/
        result.res = res;
        result.wIdx;
        result.cleanData = cleanData;
        return result;
    }

the call DLL code:
//DWORD start_time = GetTickCount64();
auto starttime = system_clock::now();

Result result = testPhaseOnlineADA(newData);

duration<double> diff = system_clock::now() - starttime;
std::cout << "testPhaseOnlineADA所耗时间为：" << diff.count() << "s" << std::endl;

I used "const" data to reduce the memory and try to reduce the calculation time.
Also, I used to make the data all in DLL then can reduce the data transmission loss.
I hope the DLL can also run like my cpp code and the 10 rounds can take within 400ms.
I want to know if the DLL will be slower if I use this DLL in Unity/Android because I used the acceleration function of Visual Studio debugging
-------------add in 2024.04.11----------------------
Add comments about trying and wondering:

I considered the DLL load time and tried the second, and third but the calculated time was not reduced. What I need to add is I call the DLL at the beginning of the main function, not in the while loop. The calculated data is huge so I need to cut them to 50*140 parts, every part has three dimensions……
I used the "const vector<vector>& newData". It's still time out 400ms. And there was a very strange situation, I used "const vector<vector>& newData" in the getWarmFilter(), and it cost over 30ms…… making the program slower than before.

Add Test information:

I thought maybe MKL made the DLL slower than before, but I commented out the MKL code. It runs 1ms slower, so I'm sure it's not an MKL calculation issue.
I calculated getWarmFilter() and testPhaseADA() separately and found that testPhaseADA in cpp only takes about 40ms, if it becomes a DLL and calls it on cpp, it takes about 70ms. The algorithm only calculates 10 rounds, and each round takes 30ms more. After 10 rounds, it exceeds 400ms and even reaches 500ms.
Through the new test, I put a timer in testPhaseADA() and found that this function in the DLL still takes 70ms... So is there something wrong with the way I package the DLL, causing it not to run as fast as in the cpp program? I use "C/C++->Optimization->Optimization->Maximum Optimization (Preferred for Speed) (/O2)" and "C/C++->Optimization->Optimize for Size and Speed->Code Speed Limited (/Ot)". Does it change the speed of the program but doesn't affect the DLL? Because I reset this setting and built a new DLL and the speed becomes slow, each round costs 100ms so it is useful in compiling the DLL. But it is not as fast as the cpp program after I compile the DLL.


Possibly the extra time is the dll being loaded into memory. But why do you need that code in a dll rather than in the main application?

Make your newData parameter a const reference to ensure that no data copy is occurring. (const std::vector<std::vector<double>> & newData)

If you care about performance, don't use vectors of vectors (of vectors...). Use a single continuous vector and compute indexes properly.

Are you sure the result cannot be explained by inlining and/or copy elision?

Loading a DLL the first time has a time penalty. Call the function prior to your timing, then time it for a second call, to eliminate the initial penalty.

@OldBoy Because I need to use this algorithm in another platform like Unity/Android or anywhere……

@prapin Yes, I wrote this code and find if I want to have the same performance as Matlab I should consider the single continuous vector but this algorithm is huge, I translated it to cpp and then found this situation……But now if only in the cpp application, I can make the algorithm calculate in the 400ms, In fact in 300ms……But after I make DLL the time is over 400ms So I feel more and more confused.

Why do you actually need this code in a DLL? Unless you are sharing it with many other applications it is of no benefit.
